# Projective dimension of ideal sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. Consider $Y$ subscheme of $X$ of codimension $\geq 2$. Can we say anything about projective dimension of the ideal sheaf of $Y$ in general?

Comment: It can be as large as $\dim X-1$. Not much else can be said in general.

Comment: If the subscheme $Y$ is a locally complete intersection (e.g. if $Y$ is smooth) then the projective dimension is equal to $codim(Y) - 1$.

Comment: @Sasha, thank you. What is the proof?

Comment: @user52991: Look for "regular sequence" and "Koszul complex".